# Compare Strings is not working

Tags: string

I am comparing string variable with hardcoded ones but the value is returning false.Even I  tried with equals() and its returns false.

Here is the apex code

```
            String myadd ='';
            myadd = newAddress[0];
            system.debug(myadd);
            system.debug(myadd =='1250 20th Street NW');
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have trailing whitespace? Try using `myAdd.trim()` instead.

Comment: you are right.Thank you.Can you please post as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have trailing whitespace? Try using `myAdd.trim()` instead.